# zsh ignores zshrc most of the time (but not always)

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, nixos

So when I open a new terminal (kitty) my `~/.zshrc` is sourced perfectly fine, oh-my-zsh works, plugins are loaded as well as the p10k theme. *But* if I, for example, simply run `zsh` (or `tmux`) I get a shell that has sourced `/etc/zshrc` fine but it never even tries to check if `~/.zshrc` exists. (I checked with `zsh -x`. I have also set up symlinks from `$ZDOTDIR/zshrc` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` (just in case) pointing to the same file as `~/.zshrc` does.)

I have double-checked `/etc/passwd` just to confirm and my user has zsh as the default shell. This is set up using NixOS's config. Relevant parts of that config:

```
programs.zsh.enable = true;
users.defaultUserShell = pkgs.zsh;
environment.shells = with pkgs; [ zsh ];
```

I haven't been able to find any weirdness in `/etc/zshenv` or `/etc/zshrc`.

I have checked that the shell I'm using in all the above cases are indeed zsh, and the same one that is run by default in a new terminal window.

No weirdness with permissions.

If I run `source ~/.zshrc` it looks like everything is working as it should.

Weirdly enough, I do update `PATH` in my `.zshrc`, and *that* update actually persists, but things like, just as an example, `ZSH_THEME` is empty.

Anyone ever had this happen? Or maybe just an idea as to where to try to look that I haven't already?

Oh, and everything is updated, as of about an hour ago.

Comment: You said your `PATH` persists. If in `zsh -x` uou see it doesn't read your `.zshrc`, how do you think it reads it? Maybe you have the same `PATH` defined in a different file?

Comment: What happens when you start `zsh` with `zsh -i`? `~/.zshrc` is only sourced in interactive shells, i.e. shells where the output is a terminal. Something may be interfering with the detection of the output; `-i` will force it to behave as an interactive shell.

Comment: @aviro honestly, I have no idea! I add ~/.local/bin in .zshrc and it's still set, but I can't find any references to that in any of the system-wide files.. Quite the conundrum!

Comment: @Gairfowl interesting point! Unfortunately, that didn't make any difference, same behavior :/

Comment: Darn. Something else to try: `/usr/bin/env -i /bin/zsh`. This will prevent the new shell from inheriting most environment variables (like `path`). There may be an environment variable that's causing some branching in the various startup files. If so, finding that will likely require even more tracing through the massive output from `set -x` (sorry).

Comment: @Gairfowl huh, very interesting! Running `zsh` via `env` like that worked *almost* perfectly! A simple `export TERM=xterm-256color` seemed to have ensured that everything looked and worked perfectly though. Will play around with `set -x` and see if I can figure something out!

Comment: `export TERM="xterm-kitty"` worked too, which I believe is what kitty sets it to by default when starting a new terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after endless fiddling and even switching from NixOS to Arch on my desktop I finally figured out what the problem was! Turns out that when I set `ZDOTDIR` in my `.zshrc` `zsh` started ignoring not only the one in `~/` but the one in `$ZDOTDIR/` as well. I'm pretty sure it didn't start ignoring it at first, which is why I didn't realize it was the problem earlier...

Comment: If you want to set `ZDOTDIR`, it would be better to do so in a file whose location is not determined by `$ZDOTDIR`. One such file is `$HOME/.zshenv`. Setting it there may clear up some confusion.

Comment: @Kusalananda heh yeah that makes sense, thank you! I think I put it in there when I was having an argument with compinit and some oyher stuff that refused to go away from `~/` like I told it to..